# How to prove a formula involving polynomial sequences and their recursive representation

Tags: recurrence-relations

If we have a sequence defined by the polynomial $a_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{m}c_kn^k$, then how can we prove that $a_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k} (-1)^{k-1}a_{n-k}$?

*Edited to fix the typo, and also simplified

Comment: Have you tried induction? It is a messy way, but would certainly work. I don't see any other way to attack the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z\rangle$ be a bi-infinite sequence. For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $\nabla a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$; $\nabla$ is the backward difference operator, and it’s not hard to see that it’s linear. Then

$$\nabla^ma_n=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(-1)^ka_{n-k}$$

for all $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$. This is easily proved by induction on $m$; the induction step is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(-1)^k(a_{n-k}-a_{n-k-1})&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(-1)^ka_{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(-1)^ka_{n-(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(-1)^ka_{n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\binom{m}{k-1}(-1)^ka_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\left(\binom{m}k+\binom{m}{k-1}\right)(-1)^ka_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}k(-1)^ka_{n-k}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Next note that

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla n^k&=n^k-(n-1)^k\\
&=n^k-\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}\ell(-1)^\ell n^{k-\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^k\binom{k}\ell(-1)^{\ell+1}n^{k-\ell}\\
&=kn^{k-1}+\sum_{\ell=2}^k(-1)^{\ell+1}n^{k-\ell}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and an easy proof by induction shows that $\nabla^kn^k=k!$, and $\nabla^mn^k=0$ for $m>k$.

Now let

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^mc_kn^k\;;$$

$a_n$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ in $n$, so

$$0=\nabla^{m+1}a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}k(-1)^ka_{n-k}\;,$$

and

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}k(-1)^{k-1}a_{n-k}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

The LHS is $$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^m c_k  n^k$$ and the RHS is (typo in the
leading term corrected)

$$(-1)^{m} a_{n-m-1}
+\sum_{p=1}^m {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} a_{n-p}.$$

Following @MartyCohen we merge these two to get

$$\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} a_{n-p}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} 
\sum_{k=0}^m c_k (n-p)^k
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} (n-p)^k.$$

Working with the inner sum we introduce

$$(n-p)^k =
\frac{k!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \exp((n-p)z) \; dz.$$

This yields for the double sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\frac{k!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}}
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} \exp((n-p)z) \; dz
\\ = -\sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\frac{k!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \exp(nz)
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p} \exp(-pz) \; dz.$$

The inner sum is

$$(1-\exp(-z))^{m+1} - 1.$$

We thus require

$$k! [z^k] \exp(nz) (1-\exp(-z))^{m+1} - k! [z^k] \exp(nz).$$

There   are   two  pieces   here.    Since  $1-\exp(-z)   =   z   -
\frac{1}{2}z^2+\cdots$ the exponentiated  component of the first piece
starts at $z^{m+1}.$ But $k\le m$ so we have a contribution of zero.
The second piece yields $$-n^k.$$

The result then becomes

$$\sum_{k=0}^m c_k n^k = a_n$$

which is the claim.

Comment: +1. This is the path I'll take about it. I don't know ( I didn't work  out anything ) but maybe it's better to start with the $n^{k}$-integral representation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof
based on 
the start of
Marko Riedel's proof
that only uses
standard algebra
and the fact that
the $m$-th difference
of $x^k$ is zero
if
$m> k$.

The LHS is $$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^m c_k  n^k$$ and the RHS is (typo in the
leading term corrected
and the term
$p=m+1$ placed in the sum)

$s_n
=\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} a_{n-p}
$.

The sum is

$\begin{array}\\
s_n
&=\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} 
\sum_{k=0}^m c_k (n-p)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} (n-p)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}n^j(-p)^{k-j}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m c_k
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}n^j(-1)^{k-j}p^{k-j}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m c_k 
\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}n^j
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m 
\sum_{k=j}^m c_k \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}n^j
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m n^j
\sum_{k=j}^m c_k \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m n^j
\sum_{k=0}^{m-j} c_{k+j} \binom{k+j}{j}(-1)^{k}
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k}\\
\end{array}
$

so we are done if
we can show that

$c_j
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-j} c_{k+j} \binom{k+j}{j}(-1)^{k}
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k}
$

or,
splitting this
into the
cases $k=0$
and $k > 0$,

$ \sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} 
= 1
$

and

$ \binom{k+j}{j}(-1)^{k}
\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k}
= 0
$.

The case $k=0$ is

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=1+\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p}\\
&=(1-1)^{m+1}
\end{array}
$

which is true.

The case $k>0$
is true if
$ 0
=\sum_{p=1}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p} (-1)^{p-1} p^{k}
$
which is true if
$ 0
=\sum_{p=0}^{m+1} {m+1\choose p}(-1)^p p^{k}
$
since $p^k = 0$
for $p=0$ and $k > 0$.

But this is true
since it states that
the $m+1$ difference
of $x^k$
is zero,
and this is true since
$k \le m$.